# validate correctness of prediction

Tags: prediction, anomaly-detection

I have two datasets. 1st contains original data. 2nd contains predicted data. I want to count how well the prediction was. I was assuming following algorithm:

1. Calculate absolute difference between original and prediction
2. Divide this absolute difference by largest number found in original dataset
3. The result should be numbers from 0 to 1 where 1 represents worst prediction and 0 best

e.g:

```
O;P;ERR
10;0;1
10;5;0.5
3;7;0.4
9;1;0.8
```

Is this correct approach or is there any better methods? Thank you very much.

Comment: I've mostly seen mean squared error or mean absolute deviation as the main accuracy metrics.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing anything else about your data (like the scale of the variables), I think that's a perfectly fine way to do it. It constitutes a simple rescaling of absolute error, which is a common error metric. Another common choice is squared error, which differs from absolute error in that it penalizes larger differences more harshly.